# Breaking a total down by months

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sales figure and the number of days for that project to end. I want to see the month wise split based on the amount and the days left.

Eg in the attached image, I have a figure of ~8M in column V and days in column U. I want to see the split from June to May'24.In case the total days are exhausted the next column should not return anything (the red cell in the example, else it should continue till the last.
1 approach is 8M/210 days*30 (june), 8M/210 days*31 (july),8M/210 days*31(Aug)...but unable to figure it out how to stop it at dec in the above case as project is getting over in dec'2023.

[image]

Comment: "Data calculation in excel" is not a useful title. *Everything* in excel is data calculation!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is overcomplicated - but it gives you the correct result.

The challenge is to identify the last month which might be "incomplete".

E.g.
row 10 in your screenshot: you have only $ 1.068.493 as amount - but your value for june shows $1.232.877 - that's because only 26 days are left (june has 30 days).
row 11 in your screenshot: for december there are only 27 days left - not 31!

```vb
=LET(startDate, D1, data,A2:C3,
λDaysMonth,LAMBDA(m,DAY(EOMONTH(m,0))),
DROP(IFNA(
    REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)), LAMBDA(r,i,
       LET( endDate,INDEX(data,i,1),cntDays,INDEX(data,i,2),amount,INDEX(data,i,3), amountPerDay,amount/cntDays,
            cntMonths,DATEDIF(startDate,endDate,"M")+1,
            months,EDATE(startDate,SEQUENCE(1,cntMonths,0)),
            daysLeft,SCAN(cntDays,months,LAMBDA(r,m,r-IF(m<>startDate, DaysMonth(EDATE(m,-1)),0))),
            x,MAP(SEQUENCE(1,cntMonths,1),LAMBDA(i,amountPerDay* MIN(INDEX(daysLeft,1,i),λDaysMonth(INDEX(months,1,i)) ))),
            VSTACK(r,x)))),""),1))
```

That's why the formula calculates `daysLeft` per month. And then checks for the `MIN` value of `daysLeft` and `daysMonth`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed complicated - but I'll try and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

In cell W11 try this formula

```
=IF(SUM($W$1:W$1)<$U11,($V11/$U11)*W$1,"")
```

Comment: THank you could you please explain what it is doing.

Comment: @himesh sum the days of month (in row1) and does your calculcation until smaller than days to the end. There can a be a rest value if the end of the project is within a month. (not at the end.)  In this case replace `$W$1:W$1` with `$V$1:V$1`